# How can I write a namespace agnostic XPath query using XPath axes

Tags: xml, xpath

let's say I have the XML presented below:

```
<ns1:test xmlns:ns1="http://www.w3.org/TR/html3/"  xmlns:UML="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
    <UML:Class name="test1">
        <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
            <UML:Stereotype name="AFV"/>
        </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
    </UML:Class>
    <UML:Class name="test2" >
        <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
            <UML:Stereotype name="AFV"/>
        </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
    </UML:Class>
    <UML:Class name="test3" >
        <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
            <UML:Stereotype name="RCS"/>
        </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
    </UML:Class>
    <UML:Class name="test4" >
        <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
            <UML:Stereotype name="DFK"/>
        </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
    </UML:Class>
    <UML:Class name="test5" >
        <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
            <UML:Stereotype name="DSO"/>
        </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
    </UML:Class>
</ns1:test>
```

How can I write a namespace agnostic XPath query which will get all "Class" elements containing a "Stereotype" element with the attribute name equal to "AFV" ?

If there weren't any namespaces, I would have use what is called Xpath Axes, and my query would have looked like this :
`//Class[descendant::Stereotype[@name='AFV']]`

the XPath query should return:

```
<UML:Class name="test1">
        <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
            <UML:Stereotype name="AFV"/>
        </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
    </UML:Class>
    <UML:Class name="test2" >
        <UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
            <UML:Stereotype name="AFV"/>
        </UML:ModelElement.stereotype>
    </UML:Class>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath `local-name()` function to match by element's local name ignoring namespaces :

```
//*[local-name()='Class'][descendant::*[local-name()='Stereotype' and @name='AFV']]
```

Answer (score 1):

And for completeness, in XPath 2.0 you can write

```
//Class[descendant::*:Stereotype[@name='AFV']]
```